# Restoring a backup gives "Failed exit code 1"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-restore

I'm migrating from Heroku's Postgres to AWS RDS. I've generated a pg_backup.dump file from Heroku, installed Postgres on my local machine, launched PGAdmin, configure remote AWS server, and used the Tools > Restore feature to restore my database.

The process completed with `failed (exit code: 1)`

When I look throuh the progress window I see lots of errors like these:

```
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.auth_group_id_seq"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 203; 1259 24981038 SEQUENCE auth_group_id_seq uohhysqaagrjqj
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "xxxxx" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.auth_group_id_seq OWNER TO xxxxx;
```

Browsing through my database I can see that everything has restored. Anything to worry about? Looks like the role name is different in the RDS database and that's all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that the owner of the table public.auth_group_id_seq was set to the default owner in your RDS instance. This likely happened because you did not have that owner pre-created in the RDS instance prior to migrating so it utilized the default. This isn't particularly an issue unless you had specific security policies set in your PostgreSQL instance dependent on that owner that you need to replicate in your RDS instance.